# RequireNativeComponent: "SRSRadialGradient" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, radial-gradients

I'm trying to use the react-native-radial-gradient package in expo. Is there some other preparation I need before I can use it, or is it just not compatible?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with that package , the best way to create it would be using `react-native-svg` package and generate a radial gradient

```
import { Defs, Stop, Svg, RadialGradient as SVGRadialGradient, Path } from 'react-native-svg'

export function RadialGradient() {
  return (
    <Svg
      height="100%"
      width="100%"
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
      }}
    >
      <Path
        d="M0 0H375V279C375 283.418 371.418 287 367 287H8C3.58172 287 0 283.418 0 279V0Z"
        fill="url(#grad)"
      />
      <Defs>
        <SVGRadialGradient
          id="grad"
          cx="0"
          cy="0"
          r="1"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          gradientTransform="translate(187.5 50.5) rotate(90) scale(180 350.061)"
        >
          <Stop stopColor={'#3730A3'} />
          <Stop stopColor={'#0F0E26'} offset={1} />
        </SVGRadialGradient>
      </Defs>
    </Svg>
  )
}
```